# Как лучше организовать архив новостей?

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно на wordpress сайте организовать архив новостей, вот хочу уточнить как правильно сделать. Через Advanced Custom Fields создан checkbox для того что вы выставлять что данный пост архивный или нет. Создал страницу и в коде страницы вывел все посты где стоит галочка что новость архивная.

Теперь в чем загвоздка к этой новости добавлены несколько рубрик, а мне нужно что бы новость не отображалась в рубриках и была исключительно только в Архиве. 
Может есть другой вариант добавления новости в Архив?

Comment: А просто создать рубрику "архив" и переносить туда посты - не вариант?   Или метку. Причем тут php вообще

Comment: php при том что нужно править файлы wordpress. А на счет рубрики, нужно что бы рубрика архив не отображалась в общем списке рубрик

Comment: Так может ты еще на форум филологов напишешь? Ты же на русском пишешь.